# How to speed up for loop in R

Tags: r

I am trying to find string composition between two words.

If the letters in **kind** object is present in the **word** object and also sequence in nature then I am terming it as POSITIVE else **NEGATIVE**.

Eg. kind[2] value "crnas" has all its characters present in the word "coronavirus" and also the characters  are sequence in nature hence "POSITIVE"

kind[3] value "onarous" has all its characters present in the word "coronavirus" but "ona**rous**" is not sequence in nature with "coronavirus" hence "NEGATIVE"

**ISSUE :**

Is there a way to speed up the **for loop** , when I tried for huge set of input constraint test case it takes more time to respond.

**Constraints:**

1<= |word|<= |Kind|<= 10^5

```
input <- c("coronavirus", "4", "abcde", "crnas", "onarous", "ravus")
word <- (input[1])
total <- as.numeric(input[2])
kind <- input[-c(1,2)]

e <- unlist(strsplit(word, ""))

invisible(lapply(kind,function(x) {

    if (length(x) > length(word)) {
    cat("NEGATIVE",sep='\n') 
    }
    index=1;
    
    f <- unlist(strsplit(x, ""))
    for (i in 1:(length(e)-1)) {
    
                    
        if(e[i] == f[index])
        {
          index<-index+1;
        }           

    }
    if (index == nchar(x))
    {
        cat("POSITIVE",sep='\n')
    }
    else
    {
      cat("NEGATIVE",sep='\n')   
    }   
}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer**

You can use regular expressions with `grepl`:

```r
g <- sapply(strsplit(kind, ""), paste, collapse = ".*")
x <- sapply(g, grepl, word)
c("NEGATIVE", "POSITIVE")[x + 1]

# [1] "NEGATIVE" "POSITIVE" "NEGATIVE" "POSITIVE"
```

For a slightly faster result, use `x <- stringr::str_detect(word, g)`.

**Rationale**

There may be a specific function for this, but essentially you just want to see whether the order of the letters is respected, regardless of whether there are any other letters in between. With regular expressions, we can do this with `.*`, which means "any character, 0 or more times". So, we construct a string like `c.*r.*n.*a.*s` which we can test against `coronavirus`, which we can do with `grepl`:

```r
sapply(g, grepl, word)
#      a.*b.*c.*d.*e       c.*r.*n.*a.*s o.*n.*a.*r.*o.*u.*s       r.*a.*v.*u.*s 
#              FALSE                TRUE               FALSE                TRUE
```

This returns a logical vector, which we can then use for whatever we want, like selecting `"NEGATIVE"` or `"POSITIVE"`.

Comment: Thanks for the code..it works fine on most of my input cases.. But it failed on below  test case .. input <- c("coronavirus.*", "2", "c.*","ravus")

Comment: Just do a check if everything is just letters: `x <- grepl("^[a-zA-Z]+$", kind); 
x[x] <- sapply(g[x], grepl, word)`